Can a small piece of paper you write notes on be called a sticker?
I think these are stickers (a small piece of paper or plastic with a picture or writing on one side and glue or another similar substance on the other side, so that it will fasten to a surface:)

(source)
These above stickers have strong sticky substance and won't come off anytime soon.
There are small pieces of paper you write notes on to remind you about things. They have sticky substance on their top parts only. And they might come off after a week because the sticky substance is not so strong.
Are these called stickers?

(Source)
NOTE: I heard a native American English kid say "They're so many stickers" (picture 2) in a YouTube video.

Nastya with friends in a large collection of adventures for kids 1:49

You can google this. Vote to close.

@Lambie, so the native English speaker kid is wrong then.

[the second picture]. Like I said, you can google this. Use Google Lens.

@Lambie, I heard the native English kid say "sticker", so I googled "sticker" and Google does not show any "Post-it notes" hits

A Post-it note is a type of sticker. It's OK to call them 'stickers'.

Seeing as the children show seems to be produced by a professional crew, they probably wanted to avoid any possible litigation for using a trademark name, and just used a generic term. The term sticker/stickers is fine in this case.

There's a brand name associated with these. They're often called Post-it notes, or just Post-its.   Post-it is the brand name. However "stickers" is absolutely fine.  They are certainly a kind of sticker. Another word is "sticky notes". I've even heard them called "stickies".

@Mari-LouA - In my youth, BBC TV (which does not carry advertisements) strenuously avoided mentioning, naming, or endorsing any product so that the brands of common items depicted in e.g. dramas were obscured (a jar of jam on a dining table would be turned so that the label was not seen by the camera) and famously, a childrens' programme, when showing hobby projects the young viewers could undertake, talked about 'sticky-backed plastic' to avoid saying 'Fablon'.

They are post-it notes or sticky notes.

I updated the question, so the native English kid is wrong then

No the native English kid is not wrong, they're just using a less common term. Why are you obsessed with the kid being wrong?

A Post-it note is a type of sticker. The Post-it name is owned by the 3M company, which made the first such product.. Plenty of other companies make them now but they have to use a different name, and 'note stickers', 'sticky notes', 'adhesive notes', or 'self-adhesive notes' are common.

I updated the question, so the native English kid is wrong then

No, she's just avoiding the trademarked name for them.

@MichaelHarvey Hi! I upvoted your good answer!

At least in AmE, stickers have an adhesive backing over their entire surface on the back, whereas a "Post-It" note (a trademarked name used like the tradename Xerox for "photocopy") has adhesive only on a strip on the back, which in my view disqualifies it, as it does not adhere flat to a surface, which a sticker does. Moreover, it is intentionally very easy to remove, whereas a sticker isn't. But "sticky note" is fine.
P.S. The words children use are not always a good guide to standard mainstream usage.

Amazon calls them 'note stickers'

Who says the people naming things at Amazon are native speakers of English?  I've never yet spoken to one there.  And I qualify my answer with "At least in AmE..." whereas your link goes to Amazon UK.
